# Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev during installation ScyllaDB on ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cassandra, nosql, scylla

During installation Scylla from https://github.com/scylladb/scylla on ubuntu 14 during `sudo ./install-dependencies.sh` I get `E: Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev`. I tried to `sudo apt-get install libsystemd-daemon-dev` and many other methods but nothing works. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: No `libsystemd-dev` for old OS versions https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsystemd-dev&searchon=names ... Ubuntu 14 : Different package names https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=systemd → {  libsystemd-daemon-dev libsystemd-id128-dev libsystemd-journal-dev libsystemd-login-dev }.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in `install-dependencies.sh` script that causes this error.
The problem, as rightly mentioned in the comments to your post, is that Ubuntu 14.0 lacks the `libsystemd-dev` package: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3515

This is not the only issue though as latest ScyllaDB code requires GCC 7.3 to be built and `install-dependencies.sh` enforces it.
It is possible to install the tools for building Scylla from ScyllaDB PPA: https://launchpad.net/~scylladb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Note that you'll need to pass information about the location of those tools manually to the `configure.py` script. Unfortunately, today `install-dependencies.sh` doesn't do this all for Ubuntu: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3379

As an alternative, you can try using the packaging script from Scylla. It is well explained here: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/wiki/Building-.deb-package-for-Ubuntu-Debian